# Populate array value in gridview dropdownlist on Selection of Gridview Radiobuttonlist in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

In this post I’ll explain how to populate a `gridview dropdownlist` on Selection of `Gridview Radiobuttonlist`  using `jQuery.First` of all here is the contents of my form with one `dropdown` lists, one for MTBC and SSBC. List is given a unique ID to be able to reference them in `jQuery`.  The intention here is to display a list of record in the selection of radio button list.

```
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $("input[name$='rdbMtbc']:radio").click(function () {
                            var radioValue = $(this).val();
                            if (radioValue == "MTBC(in Days)") {
                                var options = '';
                                var serviceArray = new Array("--Select--","1","2","3","4","5","6","7");
                                for (var i = 0; i < serviceArray.length; i++) {
                                    options += '<option value="' + serviceArray[i] + '">' + serviceArray[i] + '</option>';
                                }
                                $('.services_list').html(options);
                            }
                            else {
                                var options = '';
                                var serviceArray = new Array("--Select--", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7","8","9","10");
                                for (var i = 0; i < serviceArray.length; i++) {
                                    options += '<option value="' + serviceArray[i] + '">' + serviceArray[i] + '</option>';
                                }
                                $('.services_list').html(options);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {


                    });
                });
            </script>
        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Initially,I was not able to find the solution for above topic.Finally i got the solution and may be it will helpful for others in future.

Comment: I don't think SO is a wiki site rather a Q&A site. You could have posted a question on what challenges you are facing/faced and then in answer section you could have posted this as an answer describing how you fixed it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question

Comment: But I need this topic in future for reference.Please don't vote it or close it.

Comment: Ever tried [Code Project](https://www.codeproject.com/).